# Python text extractor & organizer

Tags: python, robots.txt, data-extraction

I need to extract details of some costumers and save it in a new database all I have its only a txt file so we are talking about 5000 costumers or more that txt file its saved all in this way:

```
first and last name   
NAME SURNAME            
zip country n. phone number mobile
United Kingdom      +1111111111
e-mail
email@email.email
guest first and last name 1°
NAME SURNAME
guest first and last name 2°
NAME SURNAME
name    address city    province
NAME SURNAME    London  London  
zip
AAAAA
Cancellation of the reservation.
```

Since the file is always like this I was thinking there could be a way to scrape so I did some research as far, this is what I have came up with but not really what I need:

```
with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if (line.find("first and last name") != -1):
        copy = True
    elif (line.find("Cancellation of the reservation.") != -1):
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

The codes works but simply reads the file from a line to other and copies the content I need something that will copy the content in an other format like this I am able to uploaded on the database the format I need is this:

```
first and last name | zip country n. phone number mobile|e-mail|guest first and last name 1°|name    address city    province|zip
```

So in this case I need it like this:

```
NAME SURNAME | United Kingdom      +1111111111|email@email.email|NAME SURNAME   London  London  |AAAAA
```

For every line in the output.txt

Answer (score 0):

these are some good scraping tools for what you're looking to do:

```
data = '''first and last name   
        NAME SURNAME            
        zip country n. phone number mobile
        United Kingdom      +1111111111
        e-mail
        email@email.email
        guest first and last name 1
        NAME SURNAME
        guest first and last name 2
        NAME SURNAME
        name    address city    province
        NAME SURNAME    London  London  
        zip
        AAAAA
        Cancellation of the reservation.
        '''
# split on space, convert to list
ldata = data.split()
# strip leading and trailing white space from each item
ldata = [i.strip() for i in ldata]
# split on line break, convert to list
ndata = data.split('\n')
ndata = [i.strip() for i in ndata]
#convert list to string   
sdata = ' '.join(ldata)

print ldata
print ndata
print sdata

# two examples of split after, split before
name_surname = sdata.split('first and last name')[1].split('zip')[0]
print name_surname

country_phone = sdata.split('mobile')[1].split('e-mail')[0]
print country_phone

>>>

['first', 'and', 'last', 'name', 'NAME', 'SURNAME', 'zip', 'country', 'n.', 'phone', 'number', 'mobile', 'United', 'Kingdom', '+1111111111', 'e-mail', 'email@email.email', 'guest', 'first', 'and', 'last', 'name', '1', 'NAME', 'SURNAME', 'guest', 'first', 'and', 'last', 'name', '2', 'NAME', 'SURNAME', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'province', 'NAME', 'SURNAME', 'London', 'London', 'zip', 'AAAAA', 'Cancellation', 'of', 'the', 'reservation.']
['first and last name', 'NAME SURNAME', 'zip country n. phone number mobile', 'United Kingdom      +1111111111', 'e-mail', 'email@email.email', 'guest first and last name 1', 'NAME SURNAME', 'guest first and last name 2', 'NAME SURNAME', 'name    address city    province', 'NAME SURNAME    London  London', 'zip', 'AAAAA', 'Cancellation of the reservation.', '']
first and last name NAME SURNAME zip country n. phone number mobile United Kingdom +1111111111 e-mail email@email.email guest first and last name 1 NAME SURNAME guest first and last name 2 NAME SURNAME name address city province NAME SURNAME London London zip AAAAA Cancellation of the reservation.
 NAME SURNAME 
 United Kingdom +1111111111
```